# ffmpeg kills my audio stream

Tags: video, audio, ffmpeg, avi, matroska

i am converting a bunch of avi videos to mkv, using simply `ffmpeg -i "foo.avi" "foo.mkv"`. Now i have the problem, that in my output-mkv-file exists one video stream (fine) but only the first audio stream from my original file. I figured to map every stream manually with `-map 0:1`etc, but there has to be a way to tell ffmpeg to keep all streams in the original order?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From FFmpeg doc

For example, to map ALL streams from the first input file to output

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0 output
```

Comment: Is this a fairly new feature ?  When I try it on Ubuntu 11.10, I get the following message: "Number of stream maps must match number of output streams"

Comment: First commit was 2011-10-20
http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;f=doc/ffmpeg.texi;hb=d049257